# How to solve Array to String conversion error in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

When I run this code, it returns *True* but along with that it gives an *Array to string conversion error*. I have seen other answers but I couldn't find the problem in this code. It gives error on query line.

```
<?php
$id = ['id'];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["Email"];
$mobile = $_POST["MobileNo"];
$password = $_POST["Password"];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE sign_up SET full_name = '$name', email = '$email', phone_official = '$mobile', password ='$password'where idsign_up='$id'");
$res = array();

// /$res['id'] = 0;

if ($result) {
    $res['check'] = true;
    $res['message'] = 'Data Updated..';

    // /$res['id'] = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
}
else {
    $res['check'] = false;
    $res['message'] = 'There was an Errorr!';

    // /$res['message'] = $emailErr;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: First line of post, The problem is here `$id=['id'];` here you are defining `$id` as array

Comment: One of the input variables is an array, not a string. You need to check to make sure you are getting what you think you are. Also, you are vulnerable to SQL injection -- take a look at prepared statements.

Comment: it is solved but now it does not update row and returns false.. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would advise to look into PDO, as your scripts are vulnerable for injections now.
[Information on PDO from PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

To solve your error I think it would be as easy to change the first line of code. It says now:

```
$id=['id'];
```

You might wanted to have a $_GET or $_POST, but in this form it won't work for sure. If the ID is in the URL I guess it would become:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

If that doesn't solve it please share the error code with line numbers.

But again, look into PDO because this script is really vulnerable.

Comment: No need to switch API entirely - `mysqli_*` supports prepared statements too. And using plain PDO without prepared statements doesn't make it any more secure, it's the prepared statements with placeholders which makes the difference.